# Please Explain To Me What true in the if condition refers to?

Tags: javascript

Please i want to know what true in this if condition refers to?

```
let x = 10;
if (true) {
  let y = 20;
  var z = 30;
  console.log(x + y + z);
  // → 60
}
// y is not visible here
console.log(x + z);
// → 40
```

Comment: it is a boolean

Comment: it refers to true. no magic.

Comment: It is just dummy code to create a block scope to show that `y` is local to the block.

Comment: Perhaps it would be less confusing if the `if(true)` portion was omitted; it would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

`if(true)` is a block and variable `y` is declared with `let` within the `if` block so its scope is limited to the if block only and if you try to access it outside, you would get an error.

On the other hand, z is declared with `var` so z has a functional scope, that means you can access z even outside the if block.

Answer (score 0):

`true` refers to the primitive type boolean.

```js
console.log(typeof true);//"boolean"
```

So the condition will always be true. Therefore, such a condition is useless.

Here is what you want (to keep the block scope behavior):

```js
let x = 10;
{
  let y = 20;
  var z = 30;
  console.log(x + y + z);
  // → 60
}
// y is not visible here
console.log(x + z);
// → 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing a true literal inside a if block don't make any sense, because the block is always true and it will get executed irrespective of whether the if condition is present or not.

true represents a true value, which is a literal value anything other than 0. So if is basically used to evaluate a condition, if the condition is true then execute it otherwise not.

So if we change true to 0 then the block will not get executed:

```
let x = 10;
if (0) {
  let y = 20;
  var z = 30;
  console.log(x + y + z);
  // → will not get printed.
}
// y is not visible here
console.log(x + z);
// → uncaught exception. z is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you are wondering even your condition is true why I can not use `y` variable outside the if condition. So answer is `scope of the variable`. if you declare a variable with `let` in a block `{ }`, you will not be able to access it outside the block. If you want to access `y` put outside the if condition then it will be global.

You should read more about scope of variable in javascript